# Design with multiple inheritance and dependant parent classes

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have number of classes class 1, class 2, etc. inheriting class A and class B (but not all classes are inheriting  both the classes).

Code looks like this:

```
class 1: public A, public B
{
    getVar() { return mVar; }
}

class 2: public A, public B
{
    getVar() { return mVar; }
}

class A
{
    protected: int mVar;
}

class B
{
    virtual int getVar()=0;
}
```

Here I am getting variable from class A in class B. But for that I have to implement  `getVar() { return mVar; }` in all the classes(classN) which are deriving from both A and B.
What should be the correct design approach, so that I can give a default implementation and won't have to write same code in all the derived classes.

Comment: To get advice here, you have to make your example more "real" *(speaking of real, please do not write things like `class 1: ...` in your example...make the code as well formed as possible)*.  How is this used?  How is getVar() supposed to behave for classes that inherit only from B?  If you inherit from A and then the a pointer is upcast to A, should you still be able to call `->getVar()` on the `A*`?  Basically: if you're going to be wading into multiple inheritance, you need to really nail the use case of why you are doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define class C that inherits from A and B and implement `getVar() { return mVar; }` there. Then you can inherit from C where you previously inherited from A and B.